# Get the top term per document - scikit tf-idf

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

Afte vectorizing multiple documents with [scikit's tf-idf vectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html), is there a way to get the most 'influential' term per document?

I have only found ways of getting the most 'influential' terms for the entire corpus, not for each document, though.

Comment: How would you define the most influential term per document? Specifically, how does it differ from the word in the document with the highest tf-idf?

Comment: Either you work with td-idf on each document itself and not on the whole corpus, or you filter the td-idf-results on the whole corpus by the vocabulary of the new document.

Comment: @AmiTavory I guess that's what I am actually looking for. I'm not sure how to get the word with the highest tf-idf for each document. Sorry, I'm still quite new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you start with a dataset:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

d = fetch_20newsgroups()
```

Use a count vectorizer and tfidf:

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(d.data)
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
```

Now you can create an inverse mapping:

```
m = {v: k for (k, v) in count_vect.vocabulary_.items()}
```

and this gives the influential word per doc:

```
[m[t] for t in np.array(np.argmax(X_train_tfidf, axis=1)).flatten()]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's very much appreciated!

Comment: No problem. All the best.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain how the last line gives the influential word per doc? I am printing that line and it just gives the first 10 words from the total table..

Answer (score 3):

Just adding one more way of doing this, in the last two steps of **Ami**:

```
# Get a list of all the keywords by calling function
feature_names = np.array(count_vect.get_feature_names())
feature_names[X_train_tfidf.argmax(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Very nice -----------